# PHP | File upload, modification of data inside $_FILES

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have a HTML Form which deals with uploading files.

I use the PHP variables `$_FILES` (`name, type, error, size, tmp_name`) to store the values in my database and also validate the uploaded file.

I do most validations fine by checking mime types and what not. However when it comes to checking the size of the document, after research I have heard that the user can easily modify the content of `$_FILES["size"]` and make a fake value inside there.

This is a problem for my website as i am planning on restricting certain users to `20MB upload` and higher ranked members to uploading a max of 100mb, and so on...So of course it is problematic if a regular user tricks the code to saying the size is lower then 20mb, whereas the file could actually be over 20MB.

So the question is, how do i tackle this sittuation and check the file size properly?

Note, i cannot use `getimagesize()` since the files being uploaded are not images.

Comment: which webserver are you using?

Comment: I am sorry, I can not help you with IIS, but I am sure you have some way to limit the max upload size or client max body size as it happens with nginx+PHP-FPM or Apache.

`maxAllowedContentLength` ("specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS"). [how to change default value](http://forums.iis.net/post/1543458.aspx)

Comment: it's normal the user also could change ['type'] value ;-)

Comment: @PauloASilva You did not read my question properly. Setting the max upload size to 20mb would be wrong because SOME USERS can upload for much bigger files. So of course i cannot limit it at 20mb

Comment: @JimmyDoe yes, you're right: I didn't read it properly. Nevertheless don't forget to adjust the IIS configuration: I don't know what the default value is but it can be security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal

everyone can change request headers

the user also could change `$_FILES[*]['type']`, so you have to be carefull about it

you have to use `filesize()` php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

```
<?php

echo filesize($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']);

?>
```

hope help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using the filesize function php,
for instance

```
<?php
$filename = $_FILES['File']['tmp_name'];
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
?>
```

Read the documentation in [php manual filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)